# FileManager.contentsEqual returns false when comparing copied files

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I need to preload SQLite files from my bundle's resources into the application support directory. I want to make sure the correct files are there vs. the empty files that Core Data puts there by default. To do this, I'm using `FileManager.default.contentsEqual`; however, this always returns `false`.

I tried testing with a playground, but the copy there is creating alias files, still resulting in a `false` comparison.

In the app, the files do copy over with the same name and size. The dates are different: the copies have the current date/time rather than the original's timestamps. Using `contentsEqual`, though, I wouldn't think that matters.

**Update:** `diff` at the command line shows the files are the same...

What am I missing?

---

Here's the code from the playground, which is virtually the same as my app code:

```
// get the URL for the application support directory
let appSupportDir: URL = try!
 FileManager.default.url(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.applicationSupportDirectory,
                         in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask,
                         appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

// get the source URLs for the preload files
let sqliteFileBundleURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "My_DB", withExtension: "sqlite")!
let sqliteShmFileBundleURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "My_DB", withExtension: "sqlite-shm")!
let sqliteWalFileBundleURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "My_DB", withExtension: "sqlite-wal")!

// create target URLs for copy to application support directory
let sqliteFileAppSptURL: URL = appSupportDir.appendingPathComponent("My_DB.sqlite")
let sqliteShmFileAppSptURL: URL = appSupportDir.appendingPathComponent("My_DB.sqlite-shm")
let sqliteWalFileAppSptURL: URL = appSupportDir.appendingPathComponent("My_DB.sqlite-wal")

// remove the files if they already exist at the target (for test - app doesn't do this)
do {
    let filesFound: [URL] = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: appSupportDir,
                                                                    includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
                                                                    options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
    if !filesFound.isEmpty {
        for fileURL in filesFound {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
        }
        print("Removed \(filesFound.count) files without error.")
    }
}
catch {
    print("Error:\n\(error)")
}

// copy the files to the application support directory
do {
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sqliteFileBundleURL, to: sqliteFileAppSptURL)
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sqliteShmFileBundleURL, to: sqliteShmFileAppSptURL)
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sqliteWalFileBundleURL, to: sqliteWalFileAppSptURL)
}
catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}

// compare the copied target files to their source using contentsEqual
let sqliteFileCopied: Bool =
 FileManager.default.contentsEqual(atPath: sqliteFileBundleURL.absoluteString, andPath: sqliteFileAppSptURL.absoluteString)
let sqliteShmFileCopied: Bool =
 FileManager.default.contentsEqual(atPath: sqliteShmFileBundleURL.absoluteString, andPath: sqliteShmFileAppSptURL.absoluteString)
let sqliteWalFileCopied: Bool =
 FileManager.default.contentsEqual(atPath: sqliteWalFileBundleURL.absoluteString, andPath: sqliteWalFileAppSptURL.absoluteString)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! When using `FileManager`, one should be using `path` rather than `absoluteString` to convert a `URL` to a `String`:

```
// compare the copied target files to their source using contentsEqual
let sqliteFileCopied: Bool =
 FileManager.default.contentsEqual(atPath: sqliteFileBundleURL.path, andPath: sqliteFileAppSptURL.path)
let sqliteShmFileCopied: Bool =
 FileManager.default.contentsEqual(atPath: sqliteShmFileBundleURL.path, andPath: sqliteShmFileAppSptURL.path)
let sqliteWalFileCopied: Bool =
 FileManager.default.contentsEqual(atPath: sqliteWalFileBundleURL.path, andPath: sqliteWalFileAppSptURL.path)
```

---

The difference between the two is that `path` generates a file system-type path:

```
/var/folders/kb/y2d_vrl133d1b04_5kc3kw880000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/resources/238FF955-236A-42FC-B6EA-9A74FC52F235/My_DB.sqlite
```

whereas `absoluteString` generates a browser-friendly path:

```
file:///var/folders/kb/y2d_vrl133d1b04_5kc3kw880000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/resources/238FF955-236A-42FC-B6EA-9A74FC52F235/My_DB.sqlite
```

---

*Note*: `path` also works in the playground with the alias files.