# How do i get the downloads directory's path for iOS through Swift?

Tags: swift

How would i go about reading all the files in the downloads directory for iOS?

I tried this piece of code but its not printing anything

```
do {
     try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(
         atPath: FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.downloadsDirectory, 
         in: .allDomainsMask)[0].absoluteString)
     .forEach { print($0) }
   } catch {}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileManager.contentsEqual returns false when comparing copied files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132067/filemanager-contentsequal-returns-false-when-comparing-copied-files)

Answer (score -1):

Try?

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let downloadsUrl = fileManager.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

do {
    if let directoryUrls = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: downloadsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsSubdirectoryDescendants) {
        print(directoryUrls)
    }
}
```

I don't think this is GOAT approach, but I've got something similar working for Documents directory, and it seems to be an alt to the sample you provided.

(marked for community so others can improve/clarify)